# Inequality involving cyclotomic polynomial

Tags: number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $\alpha>1$, $p$ a prime number and $\phi_{k}(X)$ the $k$-th cyclotomic polynomial. I want to prove that

$$
\phi_{k}(\alpha^p)-\phi_{k}(\alpha)\neq 0
$$

**My attempt**

Still I do not have any aproach because the generality of the problem. However, since $\alpha>1$,  I think that $\alpha^p$ "must to dominate"

Comment: I´m sorry again. If a is an integer such that is not the d−th power of any integer number for d a divisor of n, then α is the only n−th root of a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Cyclotomic polynomials are products of linear factors of the form $X-\zeta$, where $\zeta$ is on the unit circle. If $\alpha,p>1$ then $\alpha^p$ is further from the unit circle than $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you @Servaes